Add sound effect in laravel filament polling
I'm working on a Laravel Filament widget and I want to create a simple alert with sound whenever a new row of data is added to the widget table. Unlike notifications that alert everyone, I only want to alert the user currently viewing the screen.
However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to detect when the polling is completed so that I can trigger the alert.
i've already made custom view for my widget
protected static string $view = 'filament.widget.latestorder';

i've also already call poll in table function
public function table(Table $table): Table
    {
        return $table
            ->query(
                // some query
            )
            ->defaultSort('created_at', 'desc')
            ->columns([
                // some columns
            ])
            ->poll('2s');
    }

in my custom view, i write something like this
<div class="grid w-full" style="--cols-default: repeat(1, minmax(0, 1fr)); --cols-lg: repeat(1, minmax(0, 1fr));">
    {{ $this->table }}
</div>

@script
    <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        console.log('okey');
        // Retrieve the previous state from session storage
        let previousTableData = sessionStorage.getItem('previousTableData');
        const tableSelector = '.filament-tables-table';

        if (!previousTableData) {
            // Initialize session storage if not set
            const tableElement = document.querySelector(tableSelector);
            previousTableData = tableElement ? tableElement.innerHTML : '';
            sessionStorage.setItem('previousTableData', previousTableData);
        }

        // Listen for Filament's polling refresh event
        Livewire.hook('message.processed', function() {
            const tableElement = document.querySelector(tableSelector);
            const currentTableData = tableElement ? tableElement.innerHTML : '';
            console.log('oke');

            if (previousTableData !== currentTableData) {
                const audio = new Audio("{{ asset('notif.wav') }}");
                audio.play();
                // Update session storage with the new state
                sessionStorage.setItem('previousTableData', currentTableData);
                previousTableData = currentTableData;
            }
        });
    });
</script>

@endscript

with console.log('okey'); and console.log('oke') i'm aiming to catch the polling event. But i dont get anything in console

I think the problem is because browser can not direct play audio before user interact. So it need something like button to interact.

@Jawaad but i already add console.log(oke) too to anticipate that
